Angular testing with material querySelector returns always null
I have an Angular project running with material ui.
I am writing unit tests and my problem is to access DOM elements.
My component.spec.ts runs fine, except I cannot access HTML elements inside mat-card area.
What works:
If the element I search is outside mat-card area (here the div with 'testing' class):
<div class="form-box" >
  <div class="form-container">
    <div id="testing" class="testing"><span>Testing</span></div>

    <mat-card class="table-wrapper title_center" *transloco="let t; scope: 'companyPage'">
      <mat-card-title class="table-wrapper__header">
        <p id='h2title' class="table-wrapper__title">
          <h2>{{ t("companyPage.form.title") }}</h2>
      </mat-card-title>


And my test:
  // Testing title
  it('should have a title', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector("div div div span")?.textContent).toContain('Testing');
  });


Works fine !
What doesn't work
If the element I search is inside mat-card area (here div with 'testing' class, in mat-card-title area):
<div class="form-box" >
  <div class="form-container">
 
    <mat-card class="table-wrapper title_center" *transloco="let t; scope: 'companyPage'">
      <mat-card-title class="table-wrapper__header">
        <div id="testing" class="testing"><span>Testing</span></div>
        <p id='h2title' class="table-wrapper__title">
          <h2>{{ t("companyPage.form.title") }}</h2>
      </mat-card-title>


And the adapter test (I expect):
  // Testing title
  it('should have a title', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector("div div mat-card mat-card-title div span")?.textContent).toContain('Testing');
  });


There is surely something wrong in my selector, surely dummy mistake, but after hours of testing various combinations, I am totally stuck.

You code works fine, make sure you have no console errors, when you load the component, this can also cause failure of test cases. Check the transloco code for errors.
  it('should have a title', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    expect(
      compiled.querySelector('div div mat-card mat-card-title div span')
        ?.textContent
    ).toContain('Testing');
  });

Stackblitz Demo
Testing using Harness reference

Hi Naren, many thanks for pointing me this could be an external reason.
However, on the stackblitz demo; whatever I put in the selector the test is successfull...
What should be the good selector to reach the span content ?
I tried everything, ids with #, class with '.', ...

@OlivierTisserand the more specific the better using IDs and classes is always good
